# Is there a way to combine helm with some other tool for k8s configuration management without conflicts?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, deployment, helm, kubernetes-helm

Currently I have a k8s project with multiple services which are managed by a helm chart. Said helm chart is installed on my local machine and I want to keep it this way if it's possible. But now I need to provide a simple user-friendly way to change versions of some service's docker images for other people. I was thinking about creating a jenkins task which would allow changing "image" field for those services, but it would create conflicts with my helm release: next time I update something with helm, it would rollback jenkins "image" field changes to the values in my helm chart.

Is there a simple way to resolve this conflict, like saying helm not to change "image" field? If not, how can I continue using helm for project configuration while allowing "image" field changes from jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm isn't made to be used this way.  If you'd prefer to use a static deployment, you're better off using a plain Kubernetes manifest.  Then, people changing the image field won't break your release.

You can easily convert it to one simply by running [helm get manifest](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_manifest/) command

Helm is used to manage release versions.  I.e. every new release (and a docker image change definitely qualifies as one), you would push a change to your helm chart.

The other alternative you have is defining docker image as a value.  Then you can pass a command-line argument to replace the image tag with a new one and re-run helm from Jenkins any time you have a new deploy.

Example:

in values.yaml:

```
image: 
  repo: foo
  tag: bar
```

On command line when running helm:

```
helm upgrade --install my-app --set image.tag=newtag
```

Final, and least recommended way is to use a mutable tag (i.e. "master") and set your `ImagePullPolicy` to `Always`.  This way, when you have a deploy, you just need to bounce all the pods in your deployment/daemonset/statefulset object.

Comment: I think I'll just move my helm release to another host which is accessible from jenkins and  use your solution with command line argument then.